# Inserting (contact) a string in the middle of a String in a DB2 column

Tags: sql, database, string, split, db2

I am in need of some support. I am trying to insert a string into an existing string in a DB2 String column. I can use concat to add to the end but the issue is that I need to add it in a specific location within the String.

The specific location of the string is 18 places from the end moving backwards:

Example:

```
<option><item>The item number xxxxxxx comes in white</item></option>
```

I want to insert the word "SOLD OUT" before the `</item>` so I can apply to all products that are sold out regardless of the text before the closing tag.

I can concat to the end of the string but it won't work for the business logic.

How can I count backwards and then add the word to in the middle of the existing text and the closing bracket?

Any ideas?

I am using DB2 version 8. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for you:

```
replace(yourcolumn, '</item>', ' SOLD OUT</item>')
```